# How to get a second browser running on a Selenium2 Grid Hub

Tags: webdriver, selenium-rc, selenium-webdriver, gradle

I managed to get a Selenium Grid Hub running in my code (using a Groovy/Gradle build system), and I loaded configuration from a .json config file and when I run my tests it only runs a single thread.   I configured my Grid server to have a max of 2 sessions.   How do I get my unit test (or the grid) to actually start a second browser?   I looked everywhere on the Selenium site and on Google and everyone fails to mention how to do it, as if it is something that everyone already knows.  Am I missing something here?

Here is where I have my config files for my Hub and Node :
https://github.com/djangofan/WebDriverTestingTemplate/tree/master/root

Comment: Post your config file then only we able to found where is the mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for [DesiredCapabilities](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/remote/DesiredCapabilities.html).

In java you would write something like this:

```java
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
RemoteWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(yourGridUrl, capabilities);
```

This would start the chrome browser on your grid.

Comment: It turns out I had to set maxSessions > 1 and also maxInstances > 1 in the grid hub configuration.  Also, I had to get my build system to fork junit processes (in Gradle, that is maxParallelForks).   Got it all working now. thanks.